# Laravel sending mail with multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send e-mail with Laravel, but I need to send the customer information and the randomly generated password when sending mail.Customer information appears in the outgoing mail, but the password is empty.

Controller function

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
            $random = str_shuffle('abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ234567890!$%^&!$%^&');
            $password = substr($random, 0, 10);
            $hashed_password = Hash::make($password);
            $activation_key = Str::random(60);
            $request->request->add(["password"=> $hashed_password,"activation_key"=> $activation_key]);
            $customer = Customer::create($request->all());
            if ($customer) {
                Mail::to(request('email'))->send(new CustomerRegisterMail($customer, $password));
                Alert::success('Success', 'Some Success Message');
                return back();
            } else {
                Alert::error('Error', 'Some Error Message');
                return back();
            }
    }
```

CustomerRegisterMail.php

```
class CustomerRegisterMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $customer;
    public $password;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer, $password)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from('noreply@example.com','Some Name')
            ->subject(config('app.name'). ' - Customer Register')
            ->view('mails.customer_register')->with(['name' => $this->customer->name, 'surname' => $this->customer->surname, 'email' => $this->customer->email, 'password' => $this->password]);
    }
}
```

customer_register.blade.php

```
Hello {{$name}} {{$surname}},

E-Mail : {{$email}}<br>
Password: {{$password}}
```

And what i get

```
Hello Behçet Atalay,

E-Mail: technobecet4@gmail.com
Password:
```

How can I send two variables to mail view at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your blade file

you are pass `password` variable in mail file and tyring to retrieve with `sifre` in blade

**customer_register.blade.php**

```
Hello {{$name}} {{$surname}},

E-Mail : {{$email}}<br>
Password: {!! $password !!}
```

Actually `{{ $password }}` is escape your value `b"$%JBg±ÄzrÅ"`

`{!! $password  !!}` not escape your value

Comment: Sorry, when i'm posting here, i'm translating, my all code turkish normally. That's not the problem. I have no error with variable names.

Comment: in `__construct` did you get `$password` value?

Comment: when i used `dd($password)` in `__construct` i'm getting password **b"$%JBg±ÄzrÅ"** like this.

Comment: check once again in blade with `{!! $password !!}`

Answer (score 1):

Having them as public properties in your mail class you can just directly use them in your view without passing them using `with`. So in your `customer_register` view, you can call `{{$customer->name}}` and it will work. Same goes for the password, use just `{{ $password }}` in your view.

Btw, your problem is, you are passing the password using the `password` key and calling it using `$sifre` which does not exist hence it is empty.

Comment: Sorry, when i'm posting here, i'm translating, my all code turkish normally. That's not the problem. I have no error with variable names.

Comment: In your `register` method, make sure that you are passing the correct password when creating the mail. As I see there wrong variables used as well. I am talking about this call: `new CustomerRegisterMail($customer, $password)`. You can debug this in your constructor of the mail class dumping the password to make sure it is the right one using `dd($password)`

Comment: when i used `dd($password)` in `__construct` i'm getting password **b"$%JBg±ÄzrÅ"** like this.